# How to include resources AND dependencies in JAR?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, build

I have a Java project which depends on an external library and contains a resource called `template.pdf`. The library lives in a folder outside my workspace and is referenced by the project using `Project -> Properties -> Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jar`. The resource file currently resides in the `bin/` folder in my workspace so that I can access it using `PDFProject.class.getResourceAsStream("/template.pdf")`, which works both inside Eclipse and in the JAR file, assuming that I export the JAR file using method 1 below.

My goal is to be able to export the project to a JAR which includes both the resource and the dependencies, while also being able to run the code from inside both Eclipse and the JAR without changing the code used for accessing the resource or having to maintain multiple copies of any of the files. So far I have tried:

1. Exporting using `Export -> JAR file` with the `Export all output folders for checked projects` box ticked. This exports the JAR with the resource file included and allows the resource to be accessed using the same path (`"/template.pdf"`) from both Eclipse and the JAR, but does not offer an option to package the dependencies inside the JAR.
2. Exporting using `Export -> Runnable JAR file` with the `[Extract/Package] required libraries into generated JAR` option selected. This exports the jar with the dependencies inside, but leaves out the resource file.
3. Moving the resource file into the project's `src/` directory, then exporting using method 2 above. This correctly packages both the resource and dependencies into the JAR, but the code will not run in Eclipse without modification since `"/template.pdf"` is no longer on the class-path.

I realize that I could manually place the resource into the JAR after exporting, or keep a copy of the resource file in both `bin/` and `src/`, or copy the library's source into my project directly, but these solutions seem inefficient as a general practice. Most of my searching seems to indicate that build tools like Ant or Maven might provide an acceptable solution, but I would prefer, if possible, to avoid tackling that learning curve at this time. Is there a way to create the JAR file as specified above using only the basic Eclipse export options and folder hierarchy?

**EDIT:** Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen's comment below did help me uncover a large mistake on my part, regarding how I was adding the resource file to the project. Rather than using the Import feature of Eclipse, I was manually copying the file to the source folder through the OS, then using Refresh from the right-click menu to update the Package Explorer in Eclipse. I assumed, wrongly, that this would do any necessary updating of the project, but I also needed to clean the project afterwards to cause the file to be reflected in the output folder (or just use the Import feature to add the file in the first place).

This essentially solves my problem by allowing me to only have to maintain the copy of the resource file which lives in the source folder, but it does result in having multiple copies of the file on disk. For my small project, this is not a problem. For large projects with many resource files, however, this could result in a lot of disk usage for duplicate files. Surely there must be a way to achieve a similar result without the duplication?

Comment: So currently the jar file vanishes if you clean your project?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - No jar files vanish if I clean, but the template.pdf file in the bin/ folder does.

Comment: Make a new source folder and copy your template.pdf into it.

Comment: I made a new source folder called 'resources' and put the pdf in it, but now 'getResourceAsStream("/template.pdf")' fails when run from Eclipse.

Comment: If the file is present in the source folder, it should show up in the output folder for that project.  If not, you might want to show screen shots of your current configuration.  You _must_ make Eclipse aware of each and every thing you want in your final jars!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new source folder and put template.pdf under that. Then change get resourceAsStream() to include the new folder name as well.

getResourceAsStream("\resources\template.pdf")

Comment: This does not work when run from Eclipse, as getResourceAsStream() starts looking at the class-path which, when executing from Eclipse, is "<projectdir>/bin/" (not "<projectdir>/", where the new source folder is created). Additionally, when exporting the project to JAR with this configuration, the resource file will not be placed inside any folder, but will be placed at the top level of the JAR instead, making its path "/template.pdf" rather than "/templates/template.pdf" relative to the class-path when the JAR is executed.

Comment: If you right click the project and go to properties, is the new source folder on the build path?

Comment: Yes, templates/ appears on the build path.

Comment: Must be forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

If the jar has the file in the path say inside resources folder,you could add the jar in Project->Build path and use the following InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("resources/sample.txt");

This works for me.